# Applying colour ramp to DSM in ArcGIS using real elevation values as colour cut-offs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, dem, symbology, color-ramp

I have a topo-bathymetric lidar DEM that I need to construct a CSR for in ArcGIS 10.3. I know how to make colour ramps and personalize them, but I'm wondering if it's possible to make a ramp based on certain elevation values.

I need everything from -20 m to 0 m elevation on the DEM (ie. the bathymetry) to be a colour ramp from dark blue (-20) to light blue (0 m), and then above 0 m (ie. the topography) to be a colour ramp from green through yellow to red. I need the blue to end at 0 m exactly. Any way to do this?

Comment: You might look at this addin: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/2016/03/07/diverging-color-ramp-addin-for-arcmap-10-4/

Answer (score 1):

You could use two layers to display it. And under Symbology use a Minimum-Maximum-Stretch, where you can specify Zero (0) as the Minimum for the first Layer and vice versa for the second: Zero as the Maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can mix color ramps but you can create your own. there is some manual work involved bit you can save your ramp at the end... 
my example based on 15 classes, but you can easily extend that to fit your purpose.
All you have to do is to set the first color to dark blue (your -20m), slid down to your 0m and set it to light blue.
[image]

Set the other colors as you need:

[image]

Then select only the colors you have just set up --> right click --> Ramp Colors

[image]

And you will get a ramp based on corors you have picked:
[image]

it is not exactly you have been asking for but may help as well.